# Capture primary key value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm adding a record to a table using the following code:

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("QUOTE-Run", dbOpenDynaset)

rs1.AddNew
rs1.Fields("[QuoteNumber]").value = [txtQuoteNumber].value
rs1.Fields("[LeadTime]").value = [txtLeadTime].value
rs1.Fields("[Qty]").value = [txtQty].value
rs1.Fields("[Title]").value = [txtTitle].value
rs1.Fields("[Date]").value = VBA.DateTime.Date
rs1.Fields("[Time]").value = VBA.DateTime.Time
rs1.Fields("[InitiatedBy]").value = Application.CurrentUser
rs1.Fields("[IncompleteProblemNotes]").value = [txtIncompleteProblemNotes].value
rs1.Fields("[CustomerNotes]").value = [txtCustomerNotes].value
rs1.Fields("[Memo]").value = [txtMemo].value
rs1.Fields("[Memo1]").value = [txtMemo1].value
rs1.Fields("[PrefferedQuoteRunSelect]").value = [txtPrefferedQuoteRunSelect].value
rs1.Fields("[CombinedRun]").value = [chkCombinedRun].value
rs1.Update
```

When creating the record there is an AutoNumber primary key field called RunID that gets a value.  I need to know what that value is so I can use it later in the code.  What is the easiest way of capturing that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of for you to get the value of RunID is declaring a variable and setting that variable equal to the field before updating the record.  Something like this:

```
   Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
   Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("QUOTE-Run", dbOpenDynaset)
   Dim TempRunID As Long

   rs1.AddNew
   rs1.Fields("[QuoteNumber]").value = [txtQuoteNumber].value
   rs1.Fields("[LeadTime]").value = [txtLeadTime].value
   rs1.Fields("[Qty]").value = [txtQty].value
   rs1.Fields("[Title]").value = [txtTitle].value
   rs1.Fields("[Date]").value = VBA.DateTime.Date
   rs1.Fields("[Time]").value = VBA.DateTime.Time
   rs1.Fields("[InitiatedBy]").value = Application.CurrentUser
   rs1.Fields("[IncompleteProblemNotes]").value = [txtIncompleteProblemNotes].value
   rs1.Fields("[CustomerNotes]").value = [txtCustomerNotes].value
   rs1.Fields("[Memo]").value = [txtMemo].value
   rs1.Fields("[Memo1]").value = [txtMemo1].value
   rs1.Fields("[PrefferedQuoteRunSelect]").value = [txtPrefferedQuoteRunSelect].value
   rs1.Fields("[CombinedRun]").value = [chkCombinedRun].value

   TempRunID = rs1.Fields("[RunID]").value
   rs1.Update
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a second query that uses the function

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: This is a MySQL function. You can use this with an ADODB query if you back end is MySQL. If your back end is made up of MS Access tables, no you will not be able to execute this function.